# "Unable to locate package sudo" when i try to install sudo on new Debian

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, apt-get, debian-jessie

i installed a new Debian on a small VPS and now when i try to install sudo i just get this message. I also tried to add FTP-Server into the list and i still get that error.

```
root@srv45758:~# vi /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Does any one maybe know the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify your sources [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

Try using `apt-get install sudo` to get it.

You can configure users to use it with its config file:

```
vi /etc/sudoers

add a line:

user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: I was trying to install it with apt-get install sudo

Comment: @Janlasse Try running `apt-get update` first to synchronize package lists.

Comment: @MarekRost Thanks this works for me. After updating I'm able to install sudo.

Answer (score 6):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install sudo
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: these commands are self-explanatory, you may google and post a question on which part is not clear.

Comment: This worked for me, I had docker Ubuntu image and after update it was able to "locate the package".

Answer (score 0):

add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
```

and run `su && apt-get update`. now
open new shell and itll be available